# How to add to AppEngine a WSGI middleware that modifies the body of the response

Tags: python, google-app-engine, wsgi

Adding a middleware that only modifies the HTTP headers (like FirePython) is quite simple, but when you call webapp.WSGIApplication(environ, start_response) it returns [''] instead of an iterable with the body:

```
def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
    ...
    response.wsgi_write(start_response)
    return ['']
```

response.wsgi_write is actually the responsible of printing the body:

```
def wsgi_write(self, start_response):
    ...
    write = start_response('%d %s' % self.__status, self.__wsgi_headers)
    write(body)
    self.out.close()
```

This makes it difficult to modify the body by a WSGI middleware. Usually I would just do:

```
class Upperware:
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.wrapped_app = app

def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
    for data in self.wrapped_app(environ, start_response):
        return data.upper()
```

But this doesn't work, as the return value of wrapped_app is ['']. How can I make the Upperware middleware work in Google AppEngine? What's the design decision that lead to write the response instead of returning it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to intercept writes to the body of the request, you need to define your own `start_response` and `write` functions, like so:

```
class Upperware(object):
  def __init__(self, app):
    self.wrapped_app = app

  def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
    def my_start_response(status, response_headers, exc_info=None):
      write = start_response(status, response_headers, exc_info)
      def my_write(body_data):
        # Do your middleware handling of writes here
        body_data = body_data.upper()
        write(body_data)
      return my_write
    return self.wrapped_app(environ, my_start_response)
```

As to why webapp was written this way, I'm afraid I can't say. It should be possible to change its behaviour to yield an iterator or list instead, without breaking anything, so feel free to [file a bug](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. WRT the bug report, done http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4244